# Linux Volume Encryption: Possible to specify your own Encryption Tool?

Tags: encryption, luks, dm-crypt, volume, disk-encryption

I want to use Volume Encryption on my Debian machine. Linux does have such a tool for that. But I want to use my own encryption tool to encrypt a partition. Now, is it **somehow** possible to specify it in Linux, so my own encryption tool will be used to encrypt a volume?

This tiny crypt tool only en-/decrypts single files and runs from terminal like:
`./crypttool -encrypt -p 12345 filename.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The kernel doesn't defer to user space, and even less running user space tools, in order to de/encrypt data on block devices.

If you want your own encryption mechanism, you will need to implement it in the kernel and implement support in cryptsetup and Co to use it.

Alternatively, you could do a fuse implementation maybe, however I wouldn't recommend any of this other than for fun / experimenting.

Comment: So there really is no Kernel Patch available to support this kind of 'custom volume encryption'? Is there any work-around u know? Its just experimental, still I cant code any crypto stuff.

Comment: No kernel patch is going to magically add support for "custom" encryption for exactly the same reasons the vanilla kernel doesn't support this.  There is no way the kernel is going execute a user space binary to encrypt block device data.